# blowfish encryption with iaik pkcs7 EnvelopedData

Tags: java, public-key-encryption, blowfish, pkcs#7, iaik-jce

I am migrating my module from bouncy castle to [iaik](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/) pkcs7. I need to use blowfish,twofish and idea encryption algorithms in conjunction with iaik.pkcs.pkcs7.EnvelopedDataStream of IAIK library. Idea encryption algorithm Id is present in AlgorithmID class of IAIK but cant be implemented directly(probably because of variable key length). Blowfish is present as separate cipher class but I could not figure out a way to use it along with enveloped data(which is important because I will be using public key encryption method). I can actually encrypt using blowfish,then wrap using enveloped data and some algorithm such as aes and send this but the receiver won't have the algorithm info in that case. Secret key can be passed along with recepientInfo.

If anyone can possible show me the way een basic I may be able to proceed.

Thanks in advance

Atraya

Answer (score 0):

Hi I came up with the solution

ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(message);

```
  AlgorithmID blowfish=new AlgorithmID("1.3.6.1.4.1.3029.1.2","BLOWFISH_CBC","Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  byte[] iv = new byte[8];
    random.nextBytes(iv);
  try{
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish", "IAIK");
        secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

        AlgorithmParameterSpec params = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        keyGen.init(128);

        secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
        iaik.pkcs.pkcs7.EncryptedContentInfoStream eci = new iaik.pkcs.pkcs7.EncryptedContentInfoStream(ObjectID.pkcs7_data, is);
        eci.setupCipher(blowfish, secretKey, params);
        return eci;
  }catch(Exception e){

  }
```

Tell me if this way is wrong or can be improved or there is another way of doing this.

thanks